# Xamarin: System.IO.IOException: The file name, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm building a mobile application, however, when I try to put an image png under the Android Device (Android - Resources Drawable) I get this weird error when running the application:

```
Severity Code Description Project File Line Status Deleted
Error System.IO.IOException: The file name, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.Directory.DeleteHelper(String fullPath, String userPath, Boolean recursive, Boolean throwOnTopLevelDirectoryNotFound, WIN32_FIND_DATA& data)
   at System.IO.Directory.Delete(String fullPath, String userPath, Boolean recursive, Boolean checkHost)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.RemoveDirFixed.RunTask() mvm_guia2.Android
```

I don't know why I'm getting that, and the only way that I have found to troubleshoot this is by creating a new project.

Any recommendations?

Comment: is this an unhandled exception that crashes the app?  Or just a console message?  If its an exception, which line causes it?

Comment: This is a console error message that stops the app from opening

Comment: does it work if you remove the image?

Comment: No, it doesn't, once I have that error, it doesn't go away

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first check if the names of your images are valid.  File names must contain only `lowercase a-z`, `0-9`, or `_`.

Besies,  you can try to delete the `bin` folders and the `obj` folders and rebuild it.

If it doesn’t work, then try to restart your visual studio.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same build errors but got them solved.

In my case, it was an issue with the path (namespace), the path was something like "SolutionName.ProductName.ProjectName.Fontend.Technology.App".

I solved it by recreating the project with a short path (namespace) for ex. "SolutionName.Project.App".

Refer to the link below for more information, please.

[Why am I getting this error on a new Xamarin Forms Android Project?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/313806/why-am-i-getting-this-error-on-a-new-xamarin-forms)

Because your question has no further details, I assumed it might be a long path (namespace) issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).